# Create MySQL database in Docker container at build time

Tags: mysql, docker

I need to create a Docker image with a large database. The database can be populated using a script `populate_net_db.sh` from specified folders. I need to create a Docker image that has this done at build time so that developers working with database can create a container and not wait long time before the database gets populated.

What I have done (this worked but is not what I need):

- I can create database at run time and populate it using mysql Docker image and putting the required files into `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. This will require significant time to set things up when you run the image, but works as needed and I can access the DB with `docker exec -it "image_name" mysql -u root -p` exactly as required.
- I can create the same database at build time using RUN command and see that the tables are set up correctly at build, however, when I run such an image a new mysql DB is set up and the DB from build is gone.

Is there a way to have the build-time database show up in `docker exec -it "image_name" mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create populated MySQL Docker Image on build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482780/how-to-create-populated-mysql-docker-image-on-build-time)

Comment: Short answer: because the MySQL base image use a `VOLUME` declaration for their data directory, you cannot build an image later that has any content there; it is stuck forever at the (empty) contents at the time `VOLUME` ran.

Comment: On [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546775/how-to-use-docker-compose-to-restore-fresh-databases-quickly-for-integration-tes/52546871#52546871) at one point I had suggested using `docker run -v` to keep the MySQL data in a host directory and sharing a tar file of that directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem by saving the contents of `/var/lib/mysql/` in a temporary folder during build as: `mv /var/lib/mysql /mnt/tmp/`. Then I created an entrypoint script to put in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder. This script deletes the `/var/lib/mysql/` contents at run time and moves the saved state from `/mnt/tmp/`. This causes MySQL to restart. However, the database becomes available very fast at container run. This method takes ~5  minutes for a 27GB database versus >1hr with loading the database from a dump file.